# Database-level validation Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I need to be able to validate data on Neo4j. Eg property can only be an int.

I read this [Database-level validation of Neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23822409/database-level-validation-of-neo4j#) thread as a reference but it was at the beginning of 2014. Are there any new tools or techniques other than those mentioned in that thread?

Comment: We have this functionality in GraphAware Enterprise extensions, but they're not entirely free. Ping me if you would consider a commercial solution for this and I'll send you more info.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: no. TransactionEventHandler are the way to go.